# Could not write and save live video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv3.0, opencv

I am trying to write and save the video of my object detection. I have referred and tried based on the posts posted here in Stackoverflow. However, none of them is working.

My specifications:
Python 3.7.9
OpenCV 4.5.1

The code is as below

```
import cv2
from main import *
import imutils
import math

darknetmain = darknet_main()

darknetmain.setGPU(is_GPU=True)

saveVid ="./data/test_sampah_tasik.mp4"
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = 270
height = 480
size = (width,height)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('21_output.mpeg',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPJG'),20,size)
# initialize the known distance from the camera to the object, which
# in this case is 24 inches
KNOWN_DISTANCE = 12.0
# initialize the known object width, which in this case, the piece of
# paper is 11.81 inches wide
KNOWN_WIDTH = 12.0


if video.isOpened():
    while(True):
        res, cv_img = video.read()
        if res==True:
            k = cv_img[90:360, 90:570]
            imcaptions, boundingBoxs = darknetmain.performDetect(k)
            if len(imcaptions)>0:
                for i in range(len(imcaptions)):
                    k = cv2.rectangle(k, boundingBoxs[i][0], boundingBoxs[i][2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    k = cv2.putText(k, imcaptions[i], boundingBoxs[i][0], cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                                        (0, 0, 255))

                    
                    startPoint = (180,570)
                    dividePoint = [x for x in boundingBoxs[i][2]]
                    dividePoint[0] = dividePoint[0] - 50
                    dividePoint[1] = dividePoint[1] - 50
                    if dividePoint[0] > 160:
                        print("Right")
                    elif dividePoint[0] <= 160:
                        print("Left")
                    centerPoint= (int(dividePoint[0]),int(dividePoint[1]))
                    k = cv2.line(k, startPoint, centerPoint,  (0, 255, 0), 2)
                result.write(k)
                cv2.imshow("result", k)
            else:
                #print("no result")
                result.write(k)
                cv2.imshow("result", k)
            
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key==27 or 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            
        else:
            break

else:
    print("Cannot read the video file")
```

The error that I received is

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x4745504d/'MPEG' is not supported with codec id 2 and format 'mpeg / MPEG-1 Systems / MPEG program stream'
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your code, because `'MPJG'` doesn't look right to me

Comment: @couka , it is my code. I solved it. it seems like I dont have MJPG codec. I only have XVID codec installed. So I saved it in .avi format.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. It's `MJPG` not `MPJG`. It's short for "Motion JPG". But if Xvid is fine for you, it's probably the better choice anyways.